# How to write a txt file and duplicate it, and have it be able to run on any computer with different users?

Tags: applescript

I am trying to create a script that can create a text file with random information, and then duplicate the file onto any computer's desktop. Therefore, I might need a way of reading a user's directory.

Comment: Please post the code that you have already written and tried.

Comment: And then please tell us you're not AppleScripting a trojan.

Comment: I am trying to create a script that creates backups of files by duplicating them. My friends and I are working on a project and that is why it needs to run on multiple computers

Comment: Just don't hard code paths - use standard file locations such as `path to home folder` and results from open/save panels.

Answer (score -1):

This AppleScript code works for me using the latest version of macOS Mojave.

```
property fileName : "Test Document.txt" --value can be changed
property theText : "Random Information" --value can be changed

writeToAFile()

on writeToAFile()
    set theFile to (path to desktop as text) & fileName
    set theFile to POSIX path of theFile
    try
        set writeToFile to open for access theFile with write permission
        write theText & linefeed to writeToFile as text starting at eof
        close access theFile
    on error errMsg number errNum
        close access theFile
        set writeToFile to open for access theFile with write permission
        write theText & linefeed to writeToFile as text starting at eof
        close access theFile
    end try
end writeToAFile
```

Comment: The reason I chose the route of using a handler was because I don't know what the rest of his code is or will be.  He mentioned backing up files and I know some of my personal code for backing up files can get a little lengthy... So thinking of the big picture, I figured he may want to "write to file" several different times in his script.  That being the case, choosing to use handlers is a solid approach.  He certainly does not need to use the handler version of the code, opting to just use the "meat and potatoes" but I think the approach I offer is valid

Comment: And I chose this error catching block as I have it because in the event of running and testing the code in script editor, and an error gets produced before the action of closing access to the file... The next time the script gets run, it will throw an error because the file cannot be opened for access or written to as it was never closed previously.  My error catching block addresses that issue.

Comment: _cont'd..._ You error handling correctly starts by closing the open file resource, but then goes on to perform identical actions as before, with no error-catching in place for that.  Simply, you need to delete everything in the error handler except the command to close the file resource.  But, in AppleScript, you don't actually need to fool around with file resources by using `open for access`. If a file exists, you can just `write to...`; if a file doesn't exist, it can be created with _System Events_. This eliminates all the error-catching gaff.